# Привести тип данных к типу время

Tags: python

Считываю данные из ексель, они там находятся в ячейках с типом время. Как в питоне привести к этому типу данных, если в экселе будет другой тип

```
# Наподобие такого
t = time(ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value)
```

**UDP:** Имеется эксель файл со столбцами типа текст:

```
1:20:00
40:00
24:00
```

В питоне я считываю эти данные так

```
t = ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value
print(type(t)) # получаю <class 'str'>
# как получить на выводе <class 'datetime.time'>
```

Comment: В Python нет типа "Время".

Comment: @Никита, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects ;)

Comment: Приведите в вопросе небольшие воспроизводимые примеры входных данных и результат, который вы хотите получить

Comment: А какой конкретно тип считывается сейчас?

Comment: дописал в вопросе

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628122/5741205

Comment: @MaxU Это не встроенный тип Python. Это просто объект класса time.

Comment: @Никита, ну если рассматривать Python даже без __встроенных__ модулей, то получится какой-то неуклюжий обрубок, которым и пользоваться не хочется )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой костыль. лучше придумать не смог.

```
import datetime
a = '20:00'
ltime = list(map(int, a.split(':')))
if len(ltime) == 3:
    time = datetime.time(hour=ltime[0], minute=ltime[1], second=ltime[2])
else:
    time = datetime.time(minute=ltime[0], second=ltime[1])
print(type(time), time)
# <class 'datetime.time'> 00:20:00
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: зачем придумывать костыль, если уже есть strptime...

Comment: Действительно.
dt_object1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%H:%M:%S")
print(type(dt_object1.time()),dt_object1.time())
#<class 'datetime.time'> 01:20:00
но всё равно нужна обработка исключений, когда попадается время типа "20:00", шаблон меняется. или я что то не дочитал :)

Comment: Спасибо, вообщем я понял, что сперва проверяю какой тип, если не datetime.time, то привожу к строке и преобразовываю функцией `strptime`